# How to prevent the display of admin page in django project

Tags: python, django, heroku

I created a project in `python` with `Django framework`. And I hosted the project using `heroku`. If the project link is like

`https://abc.herokuapp.com/`

When I add `admin` to the link

```
https://abc.herokuapp.com/admin/
```

the `django administration page` will open.

I don't want to open that page.

How can I prevent the django administration page shown while typing admin to the given link.

Answer (score 0):

You can just comment "/admin/" path from urls.py

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
 # other views
 url(r'^$', OtherView.as_view(), name='otherview'),
 # url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

or  remove it conditionaly

```
 # urls.py
 from django.conf import settings
 # other views
 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', OtherView.as_view(), name='otherview'),
 ]
 if settings.DEBUG:
     # admin only available when DEBUG flag is set to True
     urlpatterns +=[
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     ]
```

Comment: I got the error NameError: name 'settings' is not defined

Comment: from django.conf import settings

Comment: set the value for DEBUG from environment so you can manage development and production ( heroku) easily